# Renaming files from CSV mapping using bash mangles files

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to rename auto-generated PDF files so that each one contains the name of the user it will go to, using a CSV map of the current name to it's new name, using what I thought was a straight forward and simple script in a bash shell.

The original files in the directory are named in the format `Cover_Letter_1.pdf`, `Cover_Letter_2.pdf`, etc. and in the CSV, they are mapped in the format:

`Cover_Letter_1.pdf,Cover_Letter_User1.pdf`
`Cover_Letter_2.pdf,Cover_Letter_User2.pdf`

I CD into the directory (where both the files and the CSV are), and tried this script:

```
sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while IFS=, read orig new; do echo mv "$orig" "$new"; done
```

which returns a preview, showing exactly what I'd expected:

```
mv Cover_Letter_1.pdf Cover_Letter_User1.pdf
mv Cover_Letter_2.pdf Cover_Letter_User2.pdf
```

(`sed 's/"//g' files.csv` was for if there are quotes in the file names in the CSV file, there just happen to not be for this first group of files)

So, I would remove `echo` to run it for real, but the result is that it mangles the files, transforming them into generic `.file` format, with gibberish names like `P4L8I7~B.file`

I ran a "previewed" command (e.g. `mv Cover_Letter_2.pdf Cover_Letter_User2.pdf`) just to make sure that part of the script was correct (it was).

EDIT: I just thought to try running `sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while echo IFS=, read orig new; do echo mv "$orig" "$new"; done` which results in it running indefinitely in a while loop with no apparent end. I *thought* that it would terminate when there were no more commas in the file, but, if I'm understanding correctly, it's just trying to continue reading lines forever.

Comment: What do you get if you run `mv -v "$orig" "$new"`? And do you get `.file` extension for all your renamed files?

Comment: Yes, I get the FILE extension on all renamed files. `mv -v "$orig" "$new"` results in an error:

`mv: illegal operation -- v`
`Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2`

      `mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1`

       `mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2`

Comment: What sort of OS are you running this on? What shell are you using (bash, zsh, sh...)? whats the output of `which mv`?

Comment: Because I just tried to reproduce using macOS `mv` in zsh and your script worked as you intended

Comment: Your edit command infinitely loops because the while is executing echo, echo is returning a success, leaving you in an infinite loop

Comment: I realize my shell question is dumb, given the "bash" title and tag, but I do suspect you are using a non-standard version of mv

Comment: Quite possible it's a non-standard mv. OS is SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the CSV file itself. The CSV was created in Windows and had CR LF EOL markers. Once I converted it to LF, it worked properly.

Comment: Interesting :). Could you mark this answer as correct?

Comment: I plan to, but I need to wait a day after posting it before I can.

Comment: Didn't know that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your command in the following way and it should work, if it displays properly the move commands.

`(sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while IFS=, read orig new; do echo mv "$orig" "$new"; done) | bash`

This will read:

```
mv Cover_Letter_1.pdf Cover_Letter_User1.pdf
mv Cover_Letter_2.pdf Cover_Letter_User2.pdf
```

as commands and run it.

Take backup of your files before running this command.

Comment: `echo` doesn't do anything here for me, it just runs, and mangles the files again.